# googlec-storage-object-creator@project-name.iam.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.objects.delete access to bucket-x/xxx.jpg

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, http-status-code-403, bucket, buckets

Trying to upload an image from server to server I got:

> [ { domain: 'global',
>          reason: 'forbidden',
>          message: 'googlec-storage-object-creator@project-name.iam.gserviceaccount.com
>   does not have storage.objects.delete access to
>   bucket-mybucket/mypicture.jpg.' } ],   code: 403,

If the image name is different, it just works.
Versioning is suspended, and there was a file with that name, but it was removed.

I even removed the bucket and created it again, and the problem persists.

No error at all if the filename is different from "mypicture.jpg"

Any help about that ?
Thanks

Comment: Did you make it? I have totally same issue as you. Please tell me If you got any solution, Thanks!

Comment: Nerver mind, I sloved it with `blob.createWriteStream({ resumable: false });`. Just turn off the resumable explicity, and the strange buffer somewhere error dissappear! (I think I should answer below.)

Answer (score 8):

I did the same thing as OP did,and had spending a bunch of hours for this, I found out the post from [google cloud node](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-node/issues/2611) on github.

> By stephenplusplus
>
> I have a feeling this is due to an issue in gcs-resumable-upload, the module behind this method. There is a PR with a fix: stephenplusplus/gcs-resumable-upload#23
>
> In the meantime, you could try:
>
> Disabling resumable uploads: **gcs_file.createWriteStream({ resumable: false })**
> Deleting the cache file that gcs-resumable-upload uses to track the state of uploads: ~/.config/configstore/gcs-resumable-upload.json
> If neither of these work, we likely have a different problem on our hands. Let me know, and sorry you ran into this!

Just disabling **resumable update** on WriteableStream, and enjoy the new world.

Comment: Thank you!!!! After hours trying to figure out why I suddenly lost permissions this comment saved me so thank you, thank you, thank you!

Comment: Seems like this is STILL a problem. This answer solved it for me.

Comment: Wow, still happening! In case someone is using `file` instead of `createWriteStream`, you can disable `resumable` in the options: `file.save(data, { resumable: false })`.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your question correctly, you are trying to upload a file `mypicture.jpg` to one of your buckets `bucket-mybucket`, using a service account with which you have [**storage.objectCreator** role permissions](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#cloud_storage_roles).

The error message that is shown makes me understand that there was already a file `mypicture.jpg`, and you are trying to override it, which [requires the **storage.objects.delete** permission](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-permissions#object_permissions), which is not granted in the role I presume you are using.

There are several points that can be covered:

1. Have you tried granting the required *delete* permission to the Service Account you are using?
2. You say you deleted the file that was already existing with that name. You did it with a different Service Account with the appropriate permissions, is that right? Have you tried uploading the file with that Service Account? Did you delete it before or after disabling versioning?
3. When you say you removed the bucket and created it again, you mean that you were trying to upload the file to a newly created (completely empty and with no other prior version of `mypicture.jpg`) and it failed too?
4. Using a Service Account that has the appropriate permissions, run
   the command `gsutil ls -L gs://BUCKET_NAME/FILE_NAME` to see its
   metadata and check whether there is any remaining thing from that
   file that may be conflicting and requires the *delete*
   permission.
5. Disabling object versioning only stops ***future*** archiving. If you disabled object versioning ***after*** deleting it, there will still be some archived versions remaining in GCS, so you should [delete them manually](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/using-object-versioning#delete). You can list the archived versions with the command `gsutil ls -a gs://BUCKET_NAME`.
6. If none of that works, how are you trying to do the upload? `gsutil` CLI tool, Client Library...?